# How can I convert a datetime to dd-mmm-yyyy Date format?

Tags: datetime, infragistics

I'm using `Webdatechooser<<Infragistics control>>` for a column which takes the datetime.
I need to convert the value entered (through the Webdatechooser) to dd-mmm-format.

Can I have snippets for that?

Comment: Webdatechooser is not well known module; can you specify what string/object you are trying to format? If you were to print it now, what does it look like?

Comment: Hi... the code given by Lazarus is working... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is a DateTime object so you can use the ToString function of that object to generate the desired output.

```
((DateTime)WebDateChooser1.Value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Should do it.